# Jenkins-pipeline Posting Failure Output to Slack

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Python script that I'm running in my pipeline that is forced to fail. I'm trying to send the failure output to Slack.

**testing.py**

```
import sys

print("Hello World")
sys.exit(1)
```

**pipeline**

```
def slackChannel = "default-ops"
def slackDetails = "${env.JOB_NAME} - (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)"
def shResult() {
    script {
        sh script: 'set -e; python3 testing.py', returnStdout: true
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Execute testing.py') {
            steps {
                script{
                    echo "${shResult()}".trim()
                    if (shResult != 0) {
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            slackSend(color: '#00FF00',
                      channel: "${slackChannel}",
                      message: "SUCCESSFUL: " + slackDetails)
        }
        failure {
            slackSend(color: '#FF0000',
                      channel: "${slackChannel}",
                      message: "FAILED: " + slackDetails + shResult())
        }
        aborted {
            slackSend(color: '#808080',
                      channel: "${slackChannel}",
                      message: "ABORTED: " + slackDetails)

        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error when executing failure post condition:
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.handleExit(DurableTaskStep.java:659)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.check(DurableTaskStep.java:605)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.run(DurableTaskStep.java:549)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

How do I send the output "Hello World" to Slack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the line `message: "FAILED: " + slackDetails + shResult())`  executes the script again, which is probably not what you want.

The second thing is that `returnStdout: true` does not return the status code, but the stdout output. So in this case only "Hello World". Use `returnStatus: true` to get 0 or 1.

Sadly you can't return both stdout and the status. One way of doing it would be to only use `returnStatus: true` and pipe stdout to a file.

The pipeline would look something like this:

```
def slackChannel = "default-ops"
def slackDetails = "${env.JOB_NAME} - (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)"
def shResult() {
    script {
        sh script: 'set -e; python3 testing.py > /tmp/somefile 2>&1', returnStatus: true
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Execute testing.py') {
            steps {
                script{
                    status = shResult()
                    if (status != 0) {
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        errorMsg = readFile '/tmp/somefile'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            slackSend(color: '#00FF00',
                      channel: "${slackChannel}",
                      message: "SUCCESSFUL: " + slackDetails)
        }
        failure {
            slackSend(color: '#FF0000',
                      channel: "${slackChannel}",
                      message: "FAILED: " + slackDetails + errorMsg
        }
        aborted {
            slackSend(color: '#808080',
                      channel: "${slackChannel}",
                      message: "ABORTED: " + slackDetails)

        }
    }
}
```

I can't test this pipeline right now but it should work.

Comment: Thank you @Michael! This solution worked just as expected.